# Graphics driver "hello world" example?

Tags: c, opengl, assembly, graphics

What are the steps necessary to create a GPU driver that render pixels on a display? Basically just the simplest "hello world" example of creating a GPU driver, such as turning the screen red or just showing a single pixel. Where do you start?

I would like to hack on the GPU directly, without any C or OpenGL abstraction or any of that. I am using Mac OSX, and I think I have the Intel HD i7 graphics card, so [these docs](http://renderingpipeline.com/graphics-literature/low-level-gpu-documentation/) seemed like a good fit:

- [Volume 1 Part 1: Graphics Core](http://files.renderingpipeline.com/gpudocs/intel/hd/IHD_OS_Vol1_Part1r2.pdf)
- [Volume 1 Part 2: Graphics Core – MMIO, Media Registers & Programming Environment](http://files.renderingpipeline.com/gpudocs/intel/hd/IHD_OS_Vol1_Part2r2.pdf)
- [Volume 1 Part 3: Graphics Core – Memory Interface and Commands Render Engine](http://files.renderingpipeline.com/gpudocs/intel/hd/IHD_OS_Vol1_Part3r2.pdf)
- [Volume 1 Part 4: Graphics Core – Video Codec Engine](http://files.renderingpipeline.com/gpudocs/intel/hd/IHD_OS_Vol1_Part4r2.pdf)
- [Volume 1 Part 5: Graphics Core – Blitter Engine](http://files.renderingpipeline.com/gpudocs/intel/hd/IHD_OS_Vol1_Part5r2.pdf)
- [Volume 2 Part 1: 3D/Media – 3D Pipeline](http://files.renderingpipeline.com/gpudocs/intel/hd/IHD_OS_Vol2_Part1r2.pdf)
- [Volume 2 Part 2: 3D/Media – Media](http://files.renderingpipeline.com/gpudocs/intel/hd/IHD_OS_Vol2_Part2r2.pdf)
- [Volume 3 Part 1: Display Registers – VGA Registers](http://files.renderingpipeline.com/gpudocs/intel/hd/IHD_OS_Vol3_Part1r2.pdf)
- [Volume 3 Part 2: Display Registers – CPU Registers](http://files.renderingpipeline.com/gpudocs/intel/hd/IHD_OS_Vol3_Part2r2.pdf)
- [Volume 3 Part 3: PCH Display Registers](http://files.renderingpipeline.com/gpudocs/intel/hd/IHD_OS_Vol3_Part3r2.pdf)
- [Volume 4 Part 1: Subsystem and Cores – Shared Functions](http://files.renderingpipeline.com/gpudocs/intel/hd/IHD_OS_Vol4_Part1r2.pdf)
- [Volume 4 Part 2: Subsystem and Cores – Message Gateway, URB, Video Motion, and IS](http://files.renderingpipeline.com/gpudocs/intel/hd/IHD_OS_Vol4_Part2_July_28_10.pdf)

The Mesa3D project says that there are a number of open source graphics drivers, and Wikipedia says that Intel produces these docs so that you can write an open source driver if you want, but don't explain how.

I also came across [Michael Abrash's Graphics Programming Black Book](https://github.com/jagregory/abrash-black-book), which explains a lot.

However that is a bit much to bite off all at once. And there doesn't seem to be any information on how to get started hacking on a GPU driver, a "hello world" project.

For example:

- To learn assembly, you can just `brew install nasm`, write some assembly, compile, and run it to print "hello world".
- To learn Arduino, you can plug in an Arduino board into your computer via a USB cable, install their software, and upload some C code directly to the board and run it, to show a blinking LED light.

How do you do that same sort of thing for the graphics card?

*The hello world example doesn't necessarily have to work (though that would be cool if it did!); even just outlining what it would take in a higher-level/practical sense would be helpful. If it's not possible on a Mac, or even on Linux, that would be good to know. But even then the question remains, where do you start in writing a graphics driver?*

Comment: It depends on what platform you are targeting. Are you happy to just have graphics output to a buffer that you can then dump to a file, but no actual display output? (display and graphics are separate things). For no display output you can just write a primitive ioctl driver that pokes at the GPU registers and does the basic operations for a start. You can probably just allocate a huge block of memory statically to play with so you don't need to spend time on memory management. There isn't really a hello world driver imo, a driver has a lot of requirements just to do a pixel or clear.

Comment: Did you found that "hello world" example? I would be very interested. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/ReturnInfinity/BareMetal-OS-legacy/blob/master/programs/putpixel.asm) is of some use.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- **Step 1**: Understand the particular GPU you are targetting (Architecture, register and stream details). I am afraid for many of
  the GPUs these details may be proprietary and you may not get it. (But as you mentioned, in your case specs are available)
- **Step 2**: Add some calls in your driver that are able to query registers / details from the driver.
- **Step 3**: Add some calls in your driver to modify registers. (Change mode etc)
- **Step 4**: You can check how to draw a triangle / quad on your GPU with a constant color. Try to implement screen clear (functionality
  similar to *glClear*) by drawing a big quad or 2 triangles or 1
  triangle of dimension double of the screen or sending some clear
  command. (whichever method is supported by the GPU) If you are
  drawing a triangle or quad, use NDC (normalized device coordinate)
  system and prefer to work in Raw windowing system or NWS (Null
  windowing system). Windowing system is responsible for displaying
  your output framebuffer after compositing or some post processing. By
  Raw or NWS, I mean display the framebuffer directly to screen.
- **Step 5 (most of the things are optional)**: Implement some complex drawing. This may involve support of other drawing modes like pixel,
  line, triangular strip, triangular fan etc and support of texture,
  lighting, transformation, interaction with other windowing system.
  For this step you will need to learn assembly. But do notice, this is
  not x86 or arm (CPU) assembly, rather it is GPU assembly which is
  specialized in handling [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD).
- **Step 6**: Implement stencil functionality. Prepare a stencil of hello world in your program. Clear the screen with color 1. Apply the
  stencil and clear the screen again with color 2. Now you have hello
  world written in color 2 with color 1 as background.

Mottivation to do this all is: You want to do this. And this will be cool.

Demotivation to do this is: Possible unavailability of GPU specifications, learning curve for GPU assembly, complexity of graphics.

My Recommendation: If GPU specs (along with assembly) is available to you, I would suggest implement subset of any available API set (open vg and open GLES 1.1) for example. To read more about these API set, please visit [khronos](https://www.khronos.org/) website.

Comment: Thank you! Can you go into more detail on step's 2-4? When you say "Add some calls in your driver that are able to query registers", up to "draw a triangle / quad", _what would that look like_? Is it just assembly (such as [this](https://github.com/lancejpollard/assembly-example/blob/master/osx/index.asm#L33-L41)) that I can compile on the command line? If so, it seems the specific GPU assembly commands would probably be in those Intel docs above, right? Or if it's not assembly, what is it exactly -- do I have to do manually wire up any hardware or can I do it all from the command line?

Comment: Querying many registers does not need assembly knowledge. Only to query internal (designated as) registers (from register banks) require assembly knowledge, but you hardly ever need it. This step is just to ensure that we are able to read the (GPU) device. This will ensure that you understand how GPU is connected on the bus etc. You don't need to manually wire up the device, but yes it a simulator for the driver is available, it may be helpful (eliminating all risks) to grasp the device understanding better.

Comment: Once you are able to read/write registers, you need to learn from the documentation about how to clear the screen (Output FBO). Depending on the GPU this method may by drawing a quad of screen size, sending a clear comman, by drawing two triangles on screen or by drawing one large triangle that can eat up the complete screen. (base = screen_width * 2 and height = screen_height) is smallest such triangle. Once you are able to clear the screen or draw one triangle on the screen with desired color, you can do any 3d drawing that you want.

Comment: Oh man this is so exciting, I feel like I'm _almost_ understanding. One key piece is still missing for me however. What is the very first tactile thing I need to do to read/write registers? Do I need to write some sort of code, then compile that code with a specific program, and execute that from the command line? If so, what kind of code is it? That is the missing piece for me after everything else you've written which has been very helpful. Hoping to do this at a lower level than C.

Comment: It depends on how your GPU is placed on the bus. Your GPU registers would be accordingly mapped in your CPU address space. I have never written driver for MAC, but in linux if device has logical address, you can de-reference the address to a volatile pointer in your driver and write directly. Otherwise a correct choice of `outp` or `write` or mapping device address to virtual address and then write to required register offset from GPU base works in Linux. Mac being the similar kernel architecture should work this way, but you would need to explore more on how basic drivers are written in MAC.

Comment: Typo: (base = screen_width * 2 and height = screen_height * 2)